# $R$-module homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, module-isomorphism

Let be $R$  a ring, $M$ a $R$ -module, $M_{1}$ and $M_{2}$ two submodules of $M$ and $\phi: M_{1} \oplus M_{2} \rightarrow M$ homomorphism defined by $\phi\left(x_{1}, x_{2}\right)=x_{1}+x_{2}$

then $\ker\phi$ is isomorphic to the $R$ -module $M_{1} \cap M_{2} $

This is always true or only when $M$ is a finite $R-$module ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is always true. Actually, you always have the short exact sequence
\begin{alignat}{23}
0\longrightarrow M_1\cap M_2&\longrightarrow &M_1\oplus M_2&\longrightarrow M_1+ M_2\longrightarrow 0\\
x&\longmapsto &(x,-x)\\
&&(x,y)&\longmapsto x+y
\end{alignat}